# How to get columns out of any length of list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, matrix

This question may been asked before, but I couldn't find the answer that I need. I'm interested in getting columns out of any length of a list. I know how to do it only with certain length.

I have to check two matrixes and if one of these is the transpose of another. Since they can vary in length its not so easy for me.

```
matrix_1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
matrix_2 = [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

This should return True.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention matrices, you should use 3rd party library `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

matrix_1 = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])

matrix_2 = np.array([[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]])

res = np.array_equal(matrix_1, matrix_2.T)  # True
res = (matrix_1 == matrix_2.T).all()        # True
```

Comment: probably the most efficient solution since `numpy` is native code (no python loops)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, yup - this reminds me of the current conversations on meta - the moment the word "matrix" is mentioned, I think you should flip to a library. Yours is equally good for a one-off general task.

Comment: I didn't follow those meta conversations, was too busy reading Hans comments :) for intensive matrix calculus, `numpy` is a must-use. For casual stuff, stick to basic python.

Answer (score 2):

pure python answer: `zip` to transpose (a classic), then convert to `list` (since `zip` yields `tuples`, so comparison would always fail), then compare:

```
matrix_1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
matrix_2 = [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]

matrix_1 == [list(x) for x in zip(*matrix_2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, but i managed to solve my problem myself. Sorry for wasting your time. The solution is really simple, but i just tried too hard to solve this. Anyway if anyone intrested:

```
def is_transpose(matrix_1, matrix_2):

    for i in range(len(matrix_1)):
        for j in range(len(matrix_1[i])):
            if matrix_1[i][j] != matrix_2[j][i]:
                return False
    return True
```